# Printing p-adic matrices in Magma CAS

Tags: magma-cas

I would like to print some p-adic matrices into a file that can then be read by magma. In theory this should be possible by using PrintFileMagma(..) but the problem I'm having is that the matrices are being produced by the pMatrixRing function which gives matrices over p-adic fields which are defined by a map. The problem is that it seems Magma wont print the map defining the field so you just get something like

"$$MatrixAlgebra(ext<pAdicField(3)|map<IntegerRing() -> 
        PolynomialRing(pAdicRing(3)) | x :-> f(x)>>, 2) ! [ 
        ext<pAdicField(3)|map<IntegerRing() -> PolynomialRing(pAdicRing(3)) | x 
        :-> f(x)>> | ...$$" and then Magma cant read the file since it doesn't know what $f$ is. Is there a way to fix this? or someway of turning this field into one defined by a polynomial?

Thank you